# Изменить value в checkbox

Tags: checkbox, javascript

В скриптах полный ноль, поетому прошу помощи, есть чекбокс

```
<input type='checkbox' name='send' value='0'>
```

Нужно при кике если чекбокс выделен, то value='1' если нет value='0'

Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
    this.value = this.checked ? '1' : '0';
});
```

Comment: Решение не кроссбраузерное. При наличии на странице нескольких input-ов измените querySelector на другую функцию поиска элемента на странице.

Comment: На странице только 1 checkbox, но почему-то не работает скрипт.

Comment: Что в консоле пишет? (в chrome нажмите ctrl+alt+i, в остальных ищите консоль, инструменты разработчика, dragonfly (в opera вроде так)).

Comment: Извините, работает, в обработчике небольшую ошибку допустил....

Comment: Я сомневаюсь в решении